# Java parseInt vs parseLong

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

```
String a = "576055795"; 

long b = 10*Integer.parseInt(a);

long c = 10*Long.parseLong(a);

System.out.println(b); //Prints 1465590654 
System.out.println(c); // Prints 5760557950
```

Why are they different?

Comment: Do you know how `Integer` and `Long` are different?

Comment: I am aware of the range, yes

Comment: Are you aware that 5760557950 is outside of the range?

Comment: Oh, so you’re wondering why `int * int` doesn’t result in `long`?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Get it now. :) Thank you for the descriptive explanation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` returns an `int`, which is a signed 32-bit integer.  `10` is also an `int`; multiplying `576055795` by `10` as ints overflows and yields an `int`, which is then promoted to a `long`.

`Long.parseLong()` returns a `long`, which is a signed 64-bit integer.  Multiplying it by `10` yields a long with no overflow.

Comment: Aah! Stack over flow! Thanks

Comment: @zack: No, not a stack overflow. An integer overflow.

Comment: I meant that as an admiration to stack overflow. Sense the tone.