# Parse long in a method Java

Tags: java, constructor, long-integer

I created a method which requires a long to be parsed. Every time I type a number I get an error saying it's out of range of type `int`. When I add an L at the end it accepts it. However, it's not a nice solution if the user of that method doesn't know it.

How can I make sure I don't get the error when parsing long numbers?

Comment: Can you show a short, compete method that shows the problem?

Comment: *the user*? Meaning the developer - it is pretty safe to assume a java dev knows how to deal with longs. Or are you talking about parsing a string as long?

Comment: please refer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093186/the-literal-of-int-xxxxx-is-out-of-range

Comment: You could read it as a string and append the L in you code then parse it!

Comment: Dont direct us to other question, show us YOUR code. As of now your issue is not really an issue - it is language design.

Comment: I was thinking if I should set the type as a string and then converting it in the method to long

Comment: NO! Dont ever EVER EVER do that. If your method deals with longs, use long as parameter - the `l` just has to be there, **where is the issue**?

Comment: @Gacci is this solution common when designing my code?

Comment: I don't how common this solution is. But in regards to those who say NO don't do that, well why does parse exists. Moreover there is nothing on the API that advises not to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Long.parseLong(str);` (where `str` is a string) to parse it if you're dealing with Strings

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590725/java-parseint-vs-parselong)

Comment: Is this solution preferred?

Comment: @MarcoGreselin preferred over what? You still have to show us your code, are your actually *parsing* a string?

Comment: @luk2302 preferred over adding an L.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when parsing, you would really need to make that L, as it converts to int. So, you should really use the "L". And it's actually Java syntax to do so. And if you really want to avoid errors, you can append an L to the argument and do a toSTring method.